# See what application hijacked right ctrl shortcut key

Tags: windows-7, windows

As a developper, my life depends on ctrl-c, ctrl-v .. and most importantly, ctrl-z!

My left ctrl key is no longer recognized.  I tried setting english language at top, but I suspect an application has maybe interfered with default control key behavior.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue>?

Comment: "Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue?" Yes -- boot Windows in Safe Mode, or to a 3rd party OS, does the key work as expected? If not, then the keyboard is probably broken -- try a new keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Nirsoft's [*ShortcutsMan*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html) lists all file shortcuts in the start menu and *their hotkeys*, if any, as well as the link destination.

Nirsoft also has [HotKeyList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hot_keys_list.html) which *does* list all the registered hot key combos, though it does *not* list the application *that registered* the hot key, a feature that would have been of more help.

Finally, as @'Techie007 states, if a program is actively hijacking the <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> shortcuts, you can disable all startup applications in Safe Mode or you could use *Task Manager* to disable them a few at a time.